# Using external ACR1222L to get NDEF Messages w/ nfctools OR nxpnfclib

Tags: java, android, nfc, acs

i'm trying to read NFC cards using an ACS ACR1222L external reader connected to an Android device.  there doesn't appear to be a lot of documentation available which will allow me to easily perform NFC communication using NDEF messages.  is there a basic example of how to use either 'nxpnfclib' or 'nfctools' to translate messages for basic communication?  the end goal is to be able to:

1) perform RATS to select specific AID.
2) perform binary read from application on card to receive ~128 byte payload.

i have both MiFare classic and NTAG213 cards available.

i am able to read the state change using the acs library but no idea what to do from there to get tag information, construct the appropriate tag type and perform communication.